# Eloquent where doesn't work after overwriting model constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, constructor, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I am trying to develop a web application using laravel 5.3 and came up with a problem couldn't solve so far.

Heres the Context.

I got a simple Laravel Model called `Section` which implements a constructor as shown below;

```php
public function __construct($title = null, array $attributes = array()){
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    try {
        \App\logic_model\system\internal\Logger::debug_dump("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        \App\logic_model\system\internal\Logger::debug_dump("create section ".$title);

        $this->title = $title;
        $this->save();

        return $this;
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        \App\logic_model\system\internal\Logger::dev_dump($e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Instance creation using the constructor seems to be working pretty well.

I wrote a function `find_by_title` as shown below:

```php
public static function find_by_title($title){
    $section = \App\logic_model\sections\Section::where("title", "=", $title)->first();
    return $section;
}
```

Here occurs the Problem (the unexpected behaviour): The Eloquent `where` function seems to call my overloaded constructor instead of the default constructor.

My question is: Why is that? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely expected behavior. As you created custom constructor, each time new model is created (in fact, this happens when you call `first()`, not `where`) then this constructor is used to create new object.

If you need custom constructor like this, I would recommend you to create static custom method that will do the same for example like this:

```php
public static function createWithTitle($title = null, array $attributes = array()){
    $model = new static($attributes);
    try {
        \App\logic_model\system\internal\Logger::debug_dump("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        \App\logic_model\system\internal\Logger::debug_dump("create section ".$title);

        $model->title = $title;
        $model->save();

        return $model;
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        \App\logic_model\system\internal\Logger::dev_dump($e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Marcin Nabiałek. I honorate your help with an amusing story: Yesterday I just rewrote the whole application to use constructors as shown in the question instead of using static create functions. Määh. What a fail. Thanks anyway